# MavenProject class, get SCM info

Tags: java, maven, mojo, maven-scm

I'm writing a custom mojo to display some project information. Part of this info is SCM info, such as commit ID for which the build has been triggered as well as the repo branch, etc.

In my mojo I'm using `MavenProject` however I'm struggling to find a way to get any SCM info. I see a getter for `ProjectBuildingRequest` (which is where I presume any SCM-related info would be). Should I be looking at the `RepositorySystemSession` field? Any help would be greatly appreciated.